# cannot find symbol variable Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING in poi-4.0.1

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can someone answer me with this error, I am using poi-4.0.1

```
error: cannot find symbol
symbol: variable CELL_TYPE_STRING
location: interface Cell
```

And this is my code:

```
 if(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType()){
}
```

Comment: `CellType.String`

Comment: Thank you @XtremeBaumer problem solved!

Comment: Small fix to @XtremeBaumer s comment, use `CellType.STRING` instead of `CellType.String`

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(cell.getCellType()) {
    case STRING:
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue())
}
```